# How can I get apache to serve static content in a reverse-proxied setup?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have a setup where my Tomcat instances are fronted with Apache servers with mod-proxy. I need to serve static content on the reverse-proxy side in case authentication closes my app session (heavy ajax app).

The idea is the browser is requesting some static content such as:

```
http://myreverseproxy.com/app/sc/skins/Enterprise/images/SectionHeader/opener_closed.png
```

Apache forwards the request to Tomcat who will serve the image. I need it to be served by Apache, is this possible?

thx!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes very much possible.

For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName yourdomain.tld
  ServerAlias www.yourdomain.tld *.yourdomain.tld  
  DocumentRoot /path/to/your/website/document/root

ProxyPass /images !
ProxyPass /assets !

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

    <Proxy http://localhost:8080/*>
       Allow from all
    </Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

I am considering tomcat server is running under port 8080 in your lo interface. Basically above configuration will proxy everythings to tomcat server except for yourdomain.tld/images and assets folder which will be directly served by the apache.