# Have Apache serve static content instead of forwarding it to Plone (++resource++)

Tags: apache-2.4, rewritecond, mod-alias, plone, zope

I have a Plone-based site, running behind Apache 2.4, which could perform a little better. One idea is to have Apache serve the static parts of the contents, preventing them from being rewritten for the Plone process, as is commonly done:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^/(.*) http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/%{HTTP_HOST}:80/Plone/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P
```

Those static contents are not all in the same place.  However, Plone provides a standard way of naming resource directories; e.g., the "browser" `mybrowser` of `myproduct` could have a file system directory `static`:

```
/my/plone/root/Products/myproduct/mybrowser/static/
```

which would be published as `/++resource++mybrowser-static`.

There is no much point in having Plone serve the static files, so I'd like to prevent certain requests from being rewritten but rather served directly.

This is what I tried:

```
# in Plone: /++resource++mybrowser-static
<Directory /my/plone/root/Products/myproduct/mybrowser/static>
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
Alias /static                       /my/plone/root/Products/myproduct/mybrowser/static
Alias /++resource++mybrowser-static /my/plone/root/Products/myproduct/mybrowser/static
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3 alias:trace3
...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/++resource++mybrowser-static
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/%{HTTP_HOST}:80/Plone/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]
```

Thus, I currently have two aliases for the same directory; the `++` version is the more general approach, so I'd like it to work.

However, when I request `http://my.site.com/static/logo.png`, this works:

```
... [rewrite:trace2] ... init rewrite engine with requested uri /static/logo.png
... [rewrite:trace3] ... applying pattern '^/(.*)' to uri '/static/logo.png'
... [rewrite:trace1] ... pass through /static/logo.png
```

... while the `.../++resource++mybrowser-static/` version *doesn't* (i.e. this is served by Zope):

```
... [rewrite:trace2] ... init rewrite engine with requested uri /++resource++mybrowser-static/logo.png
... [rewrite:trace3] ... applying pattern '^/myunitracc([/?].+)\\?$' to uri '/++resource++mybrowser-static/logo.png'
... [rewrite:trace3] ... applying pattern '^/(.*)' to uri '/++resource++mybrowser-static/logo.png'
... [rewrite:trace2] ... rewrite '/++resource++mybrowser-static/logo.png' -> 'http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/my.site.com:80/Plone/VirtualHostRoot/++resource++mybrowser-static/logo.png'
... [rewrite:trace2] ... forcing proxy-throughput with http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/my.site.com:80/Plone/VirtualHostRoot/++resource++mybrowser-static/logo.png
... [rewrite:trace1] ... go-ahead with proxy request proxy:http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/my.site.com:80/Plone/VirtualHostRoot/++resource++mybrowser-static/logo.png [OK]
```

I'd like to have **pass through** instead of **forcing proxy-throughput** in both cases.

Do I need to quote the `+` characters somehow? I already tried to prefix them all by backslashes, or replace them by `%2B`, but it didn't seem to make any difference.

I had a look [here](https://serverfault.com/a/404482/113492) as well, but `ProxyPass <url> !` didn't work for me (yet?), maybe because of the RewriteRule instead of `ProxyPass` / `ProxypassReverse` (the Zope virtual host machinery takes care of the "reverse" part itself).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make it work.

After increasing the log level:

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace5
```

... I got some additional info about the matching of patterns (at level 4).

When put in square brackets, the literal `+` characters work:

```
RewriteCond !^/[+][+]resource[+][+]myproduct-static/
RewriteRule ...
```

For the alias, this is not necessary:

```
Alias /++resource++myproduct-static /my/zope/root/Products/myproduct/static
```